# measureText() method of Canvas 2d context giving different widths sometimes

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am using Canvas 2d context to calculate the width of the text

**Ex:** `canvas2DContext.measureText('Sivakumar Tadisetti')`

I am using font as `bold 15px "Open Sans", serif`

**Issue:** Sometimes `measureText()` is giving `119.4835` and sometimes `115.3423` as widths.

Why I am getting different widths. What I am doing wrong here?. Please find the snippet from below.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var canvas2DContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

var textWidth = canvas2DContext.measureText("Sivakumar Tadisetti").width;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of a blind-shot, but to me this sounds like you are not waiting properly for your font to be loaded:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = 'bold 15px "Open Sans", serif'

const before_load = ctx.measureText("Sivakumar Tadisetti").width;
console.log('before', before_load);

// load the font
document.fonts.ready
  .then(() => {
    ctx.font = 'bold 15px "Open Sans", serif'
    const after_load = ctx.measureText("Sivakumar Tadisetti").width;
    console.log('after', after_load);
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet"> 
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

To avoid this, you can execute your code in the [`document.fonts.ready`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/ready) Promise's callback:

```
document.fonts.ready.then(startYourCode);
```

```js
document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = 'bold 15px "Open Sans", serif'

  const textWidth= ctx.measureText("Sivakumar Tadisetti").width;
  console.log(textWidth);
});
```

```css
#canvas { font-family: "Open Sans"; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Got you... thanks, but, why it is only happening for some texts. Ex: in array of texts, only for some texts, getting wrong widths